# Drawing shapes in Java

Tags: java, graphics2d

I want to have a method that will draw a rectangle, another one that will draw an oval, another for a line, image, etc.

I have tried multiple techniques I found online, and none of them work. This is the only one that doesn't crash it, and the one I have right now:

```
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
}

public void DrawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color){
    Graphics2D g2D = image.createGraphics();
    g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2D.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    //g2D.dispose();
    //g2D=null;
}
```

But it doesn't really display anything.

Answer (score 1):

> But it doesnt really display anything

Very natural, you didn't link the graphics context to the drawing function. Here is a fix:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    DrawRect(g, 10, 10, 20, 20, Color.blue);
}

private void DrawRect(Graphics g, int x, int y,
     int width, int height, Color color){
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2D.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    //g2D.dispose();
    //g2D=null;
}
```

Or, equivalently, you can create a context your self `myDrawingPanel.createGraphics();` and call the function manually (removing the `graphics` parameter)

To draw when a button has been pressed:

1) Put a JPanel to draw on.

2) Make your JPanel object from a new class `MyPanel extends JPanel`, and override `paint` method. (Or use an anonymous class `myPanel = new JPanel() { @Override ... }`). **Tip** if you are using NetBeans, you can edit the property `on variable created code` at designer)

3) When the button is clicked, just invoke `myPanel.repaint();` to redraw

Comment: Right, but i cant do this because i need to paint it outside of the class. From another class. I need to be able to draw an oval or rect. For example, i could press a button and draw a rect, or an oval

Comment: @MatthewNotReal if you need to be able to tell your "paint" panel what to paint, then your "paint" panel should provide methods to allow other classes to add/change shapes, you maintain that information within some kind of List and simply iterate this List within the paintComponent method of the "paint" panel

Comment: @MadProgrammer: It's not that simple.  The OP can create a List<Shape>, but he has to define each shape himself using Polygon or one of the concrete classes extending Shape.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Or use the 2D Shape API, so far they are only using primtive shapes

Comment: no no. Okay, how about this. I have 3 shapes (rect, oval, image) and i want to randomly draw one to the screen. And then another random one, and then another random one. and then i randomly draw random shapes. thats what im trying to do

Comment: @MatthewNotReal Try to generate numbers in range (0-3). if 0, generate rect. If 1, generate circle, etc. Learn about class `java.util.Random`